# Fermat little theorem, criteria to get the same result for $a^{(p-1)/2}.$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

It is given to find using the Fermat's little theorem :

$8^{17}$ modulo $17.$

It should be using $a^{p-1}\equiv 1\pmod p,$ for an odd prime, but get on hand solving, using reduced residue method, the table:

$$\begin{array}{ccccc}
\hline
8^i\pmod {17} &i=1&i=2&i=3&i=4&i=5&i=6&i=7&i=8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16\\
\hline
&8 &-4\equiv 13& -32\equiv 2&16\equiv -1&-8\equiv 9& 4&-2\equiv 15& -16\equiv 1&&&&&&&&\\
\hline
\end{array}$$

Hence, get $8^8\equiv 1\pmod {17}$ too.

How to justify, or derive the same from $8^{16}\equiv 1\pmod {17}.$

And, if can get such pattern for $a^{\frac{p-1}4},a^{\frac{p-1}8},$ etc.

Comment: You cannot derive $a^\frac{p-1}{2}=1$ from $a^{p-1}=1$ because it does not hold for all $a, \gcd(a,p)=1$. For $8$ you've been "lucky" because $8$ is a "*quadratic residue* $\pmod{17}$, i.e. $8\equiv 5^2\pmod{17}$, so $8^8\equiv 5^{16}\equiv 1\pmod{17}$. Not every number is a quadratic residue (e.g. $5$ itself isn't, so e.g. $5^8\equiv 8^4\equiv \color{red}{-1}\pmod{17}$).

Comment: @StinkingBishop So, need find all natural numbers till $8,$ (in the general case, should be co-prime to $p$) whose square has the same residue wrt the modulo base.

Comment: I am not sure I understand fully what you are being *asked* to do. There are various criteria on whether $a^\frac{p-1}{2}\equiv 1\pmod p$ for an odd prime number $p$, which all boil down to "$a$ is a quadratic residue $\pmod p$". You may want to read a bit on this here: [Legendre symbol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre_symbol).

Comment: Euler's criterion is exactly what you need here.

Comment: I do not think that we can extend this to $\frac{p-1}{4}$ and $\frac{p-1}{8}$ in general.

Comment: Fermat's Little Theorem says that $a^p\equiv a\pmod{p}$ for all primes $p$ and all integers $a$. You are being asked to find $8^{17}\bmod 17$... **WHY** are you doing *any* calculations at all? That's just obtuse.

Comment: @StinkingBishop first line says he is asked to find $8^{17}\bmod 17$ using Fermat's Little Theorem. Which immediately yields the answer with no further calculations. The entire post is unnecessary silliness.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Could well be, but I understood the post differently: "While solving $8^{17}\pmod{17}$ I calculated $8^\text{some other powers}\pmod{17}$ by hand, in particular I spotted the curiosity $8^8\equiv 1\pmod{17}$, how does it happen?...". Lovely to see people who, out of curiosity, spot some pattern and ask for an explanation. However, the OP's reply to my comment was confusing, so I, sort-of, gave up at that point.

Comment: @StinkingBishop This particular poster is not spotting patterns and asking out of curiosity. He's got a track record. He just is not at all ready for the material he is trying to fight his way through, leading to messes, confusion, and silliness.